# Flink InvocationTargetException. Insufficient number of network buffers

Tags: apache-flink

This is a part of original WordCount.java code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // set up the execution environment
    final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    // get input data
    DataSet<String> text = env.fromElements(
            "To be, or not to be,--that is the question:--",
            "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer",
            "The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune",
            "Or to take arms against a sea of troubles,"
            );
    //DataSet<String> text = env.readTextFile("file:///home/jypark2/data3.txt");

    DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts =
            // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
            text.flatMap(new LineSplitter())
            // group by the tuple field "0" and sum up tuple field "1"
            .groupBy(0)
            .sum(1);

    // execute and print result
    counts.print();

}
```

I wanted to read from text file, so
I changed this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // set up the execution environment
    final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    // get input data

    DataSet<String> text = env.readTextFile("file:///home/jypark2/data3.txt");

    DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts =
            // split up the lines in pairs (2-tuples) containing: (word,1)
            text.flatMap(new LineSplitter())
            // group by the tuple field "0" and sum up tuple field "1"
            .groupBy(0)
            .sum(1);

    // execute and print result
    counts.print();

}
```

But there is a run-time error.
But I can't solve this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE2Dw.jpg)

Why is it happened and How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> If you run Flink in a massively parallel setting (100+ parallel threads), you need to adapt the number of network buffers via the config parameter taskmanager.network.numberOfBuffers. As a rule-of-thumb, the number of buffers should be at least 4 * numberOfTaskManagers * numberOfSlotsPerTaskManager^2. See Configuration Reference for details.

From Flink FAQ: https://flink.apache.org/faq.html#i-get-an-error-message-saying-that-not-enough-buffers-are-available-how-do-i-fix-this